# Where to load the server data

Tags: react-router, redux

I'm using the *react-router* and navigate to a component that gets an ID in the URL and has to use this ID to get data from the server with the help of an action.

At the moment I'm calling the action creator in the `componentWillMount` hook.

This works so far, but brings a problem.
In the render method I have to check, if `myData` really exists with all its attributes, before I can really render.

```
@connect(state => {myData: state.etc.myData})
export default class extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(
      ActionCreators.getData(this.props.params.id)
    )
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.myData.hasNotLoaded) return <br/>
    ...
  }

}
```

**Is there another way to get data into the store before rendering without manual checks?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can subscribe to router's `onEnter` hook and dispatch actions from where.

```
const store = configureStore()
const routing = (<Router>
    <IndexRoute onEnter={()=>store.dispatch(myLoadDataActionCreator())}/>
</Router>)
```

So you can avoid `setState` from previous answer and don't tie up component with redux.

Comment: onEnter should only be used for redirect as it will block page render, componentWillMount seems to be the place to fetch render data.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1389

Comment: @mibbit and how bad could that be, if in this hook we'll fire sync redux action? All data fetching would be done outside this interaction, and page load wouldn't get delayed

Answer (score 1):

You should create a call back, for example:

```
_onChange() {
    this.setState(myStore.getData());
}
```

Then in the following react functions do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    myStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
    myStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
}
```

I assume you're using the mixins for the react-router, if not, take a look at the docs for it, they have some useful functions that are worth looking at.

I don't think you will need that `if` logic in the `render()` method, react will handle that with the virtual dom management and know when to load it and the data.